# Is it safe to run two concurrent makes?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Lets say I open two shells in the same directory and run make in both at the same time. Of course there is no good reason to do this, but is it safe? Can it cause corrupt build files?

For a more realistic example, I might run two separate makes in different directories, without knowing that they both do recursive makes in the same directory.

Comment: Definitely it will cause corruption, if the timing is "right" (wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the answer here is that it is too complicated to say for certain and will depend, in part, on what the makefiles in question do. The general make method of operation should make this mostly safe (in that if something is newer than its sources it won't be rebuilt) but the make file cache and order of operations (especially combined with possible use of `-j`) makes it seem likely to me that this might work but might also do bad things.

That being said if your makefiles are constructed in a "provably" correct fashion (which notably might mean not using recursive make) then it might Just Work ok.

As correctly pointed out by MadScientist in his comment the real underlying problem here is when the commands run by make collide or overlap. make itself is just what, in this case, would be causing that to happen because its internal tests would race one another for any of a variety of reasons.

Comment: "(in that if something is newer than its sources it won't be rebuilt)" Your statement is true only if the concurent Makefile start wondering about it after it has already been built by the other. It's like saying that having two thread accessing the same object is safe since the first one will probably have finished by the time the second comes. Am I wrong?

Comment: It depends entirely on when make checks the timestamps. Which might be at startup (if that lives in the file cache) or might not be until the rule that needs that dependency. And recursive make complicates this greatly since there are now multiple make invocations to deal with in terms of timing. Like I said, I think the answer is that this will not work well in general but that it might under the right set of circumstances. tl;dr: Don't do it.

Comment: I like and agree with this tl;dr.

Comment: It's not really make that's the problem, and using `-j` is not any more worrisome than not (IMO).  Any command that make invokes might have problems.  Consider a recipe that takes 10s to run.  You start two makes at the same time.  They both do their mod time checks and see that the target needs to be updated and both start their recipes at the same time.  Now both commands are running at the same time, writing to the same output file: almost certain corruption.

Comment: @MadScientist That's very true and something I will edit to mention explicitly. My point about `-j` is likely mostly (and possibly only) relevant in the recursive make scenario because it multiplies the problem by multiplying the processes at work. (`-j` can wreak havoc on poorly written makefiles all by itself.)